# Disable a button with a condition in react Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a button with a onPress function in my app and i'm trying to set it disabled if date has past, but i'dont know exactly how could i do it.
I'm using the same condition to set another opacity and its working.

```
 renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Meetup
                data={item}
                refreshing={refreshing}
                past={parseISO(item.date) < new Date()}   <--  **its working**
              >
                <Banner source={{ uri: item.picture.url }} />
                <Description>
                  <Title>{item.title}</Title>
                  <About>
                    {format(parseISO(item.date), "d 'de' MMMM', ás 'H'h'", {
                      locale: pt,
                    })}
                  </About>
                  <About>{item.location}</About>
                  <About>{`Organizador: ${item.User.name}`}</About>
                </Description>
                <SubscriptionButton
                  onPress={() => handleSubscription(item.id)}
                  disabled={parseISO(item.date) < new Date()}  <--- **not working.**
                >
                  Realizar inscrição
                </SubscriptionButton>
              </Meetup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `new Date` instead of `parseISO`:

```
 past={new Date(item.date) < new Date()}
```

Comment: In past prop it works but in button, the function handleSubscription still working, i want to disable it to :/

Comment: Does `SubscriptionButton` even accept `disabled` prop?

Comment: That's perfect hack :∆